# Using R intersections to create a polygons-inside-a-polygon key using two shapefile layers

Tags: r, gis, intersection, shapefile, rgdal

**The data**

I have two shapefiles marking the boundaries of [national](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/national-constituency-boundaries-pakistan) and [provincial](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/provincial-regional-constituency-boundaries-pakistan) electoral constituencies in Pakistan.

**The objective**

I am attempting to use R to create a key that will generate a list of which provincial-level constituencies are "contained within" or otherwise intersecting with which national-level constituencies, based on their coordinates in this data. For example, NA-01 corresponds with PA-01, PA-02, PA-03; NA-02 corresponds with PA-04 and PA-05, etc. (The key will ultimately be used to link separate dataframes containing electoral results at the national and provincial level; that part I've figured out.)

I have only basic/intermediate R skills learned largely through trial and error and no experience working with GIS data outside of R.

**The attempted solution**

The closest solution I could find for this problem comes from [this guide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140504/extracting-intersection-areas-in-r) to calculating intersection areas in R. However, I have been unable to successfully replicate any of the three proposed approaches (either the questioner's use of a general TRUE/FALSE report on intersections, or the more precise calculations of area of overlap).

**The code**

```
# import map files

NA_map <- readOGR(dsn = "./National_Constituency_Boundary", layer = "National_Constituency_Boundary")
PA_map <- readOGR(dsn = "./Provincial_Constituency_Boundary", layer = "Provincial_Constituency_Boundary")

# Both are now SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects of 273 and 577 elements, respectively.
# If relevant, I used spdpylr to tweak some of data attribute names (for use later when joining to electoral dataframes):

NA_map <- NA_map %>% 
rename(constituency_number = NA_Cons,
     district_name = District,
     province = Province)

PA_map <- PA_map %>%
rename(province = PROVINCE,
     district_name = DISTRICT,
     constituency_number = PA)

# calculate intersections, take one

Results <- gIntersects(NA_map, PA_map, byid = TRUE)
# this creates a large matrix of 157,521 elements

rownames(Results) <- NA_map@data$constituency_number
colnames(Results) <- PA_map@data$constituency_number
```

Attempting to add the rowname/colname labels, however, gives me the error message:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Without the rowname/colname labels, I'm unable to read the overlay matrix, and unsure how to filter them so as to produce a list of only TRUE intersections that would help make a NA-PA key.

I also attempted to replicate the other two proposed solutions for calculating exact area of overlap:

```
# calculate intersections, take two

pi <- intersect(NA_map, PA_map)
# this generates a SpatialPolygons object with 273 elements

areas <- data.frame(area=sapply(pi@polygons, FUN = function(x) {slot(x, 'area')}))
# this calculates the area of intersection but has no other variables
row.names(areas) <- sapply(pi@polygons, FUN=function(x) {slot(x, 'ID')})
```

This generates the error message:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("2", "1", "4", "5",  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘1’
```

So that when I attempt to attach areas to attributes info with

```
attArrea <- spCbind(pi, areas)
```

I get the error message

```
Error in spCbind(pi, areas) : row names not identical
```

Attempting the third proposed method:

```
# calculate intersections, take three
pi <- st_intersection(NA_map, PA_map)
```

Produces the error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialPolygonsNULL', 'SpatialVector')"
```

I understand that my SPDF maps can't be used for this third approach, but wasn't clear from the description what steps would be needed to transform it and attempt this method.

**The plea for help**

Any suggestions on corrections necessary to use any of these approaches, or pointers towards some other method of figuring this, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example data

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
p1 <- aggregate(p, by="NAME_1")
p2 <- p[, 'NAME_2']
```

So we have p1 with regions, and p2 with lower level divisions.

Now we can do

```
x <- intersect(p1, p2)
# or  x <- union(p1, p2)
data.frame(x)
```

Which should be (and is) the same as the original

```
data.frame(p)[, c('NAME_1', 'NAME_2')]
```

To get the area of the polygons, you can do

```
 x$area <- area(x) / 1000000  # divide to get km2
```

There are likely to be many "slivers", very small polygons because of slight variations in borders. That might not matter to you.

But another approach could be matching by centroid:

```
y <- p2
e <- extract(p1, coordinates(p2))
y$NAME_1 <- e$NAME_1
data.frame(y)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have successfully reproduced this using my two shapefiles. The results don't make a whole lot of sense, though, or at least don't seem to correspond with what [Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_constituencies_of_Pakistan) as the relationship between national and provincial assembly seats. The calculations here seem to be overstating the number of provincial seats that national seats are in some way overlapping with. Not clear if that's my error or in the shapefiles. But this is my desired output format; will see if I can use it as a basis for more exploration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't self-contained, so I didn't try to replicate the errors you report.

However, getting the 'key' you want is very simple using the `sf` package (which is intended to supercede `rgeos`, `rgdal` and `sp` in the near future). See here:

```
library(sf)

# Download shapefiles
national.url <- 'https://data.humdata.org/dataset/5d48a142-1f92-4a65-8ee5-5d22eb85f60f/resource/d85318cb-dcc0-4a59-a0c7-cf0b7123a5fd/download/national-constituency-boundary.zip'
provincial.url <- 'https://data.humdata.org/dataset/137532ad-f4a9-471e-8b5f-d1323df42991/resource/c84c93d7-7730-4b97-8382-4a783932d126/download/provincial-constituency-boundary.zip'
download.file(national.url, destfile = file.path(tempdir(), 'national.zip'))
download.file(provincial.url, destfile = file.path(tempdir(), 'provincial.zip'))

# Unzip shapefiles
unzip(file.path(tempdir(), 'national.zip'), exdir = file.path(tempdir(), 'national'))
unzip(file.path(tempdir(), 'provincial.zip'), exdir = file.path(tempdir(), 'provincial'))

# Read map files
NA_map <- st_read(dsn = file.path(tempdir(), 'national'), layer = "National_Constituency_Boundary")
PA_map <- st_read(dsn = file.path(tempdir(), 'provincial'), layer = "Provincial_Constituency_Boundary")

# Get sparse list representation of intersections
intrs.sgpb <- st_intersects(NA_map, PA_map) 
length(intrs.sgpb) # One list element per national constituency
# [1] 273
print(intrs.sgpb[[1]]) # Indices of provnicial constituencies intersecting with first national constituency
# [1] 506 522 554 555 556
print(PA_map$PROVINCE[intrs.sgpb[[1]]])[1] # Name of first province intersecting with first national constituency
# [1] KHYBER PAKHTUNKHWA
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. However, I'm unclear how to read the results here, and am not certain if the list elements refer to constituency IDs in the dataframe, or just their position in the list. (I think it is the latter.) Is there a way to pull constituency ID attributes into this so that I can be certain about what I'm reading?

Comment: The list elements are vectors of indices, indicating which provinces intersect with a given national constituency. I've edited the response to illustrate how you could obtain e.g. province names from this list.